# MySQL - Latest row by set of users

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table where I would like to get the latest posts by "post_date" from a set of users in a particular group (they can belong to more than one group). I first get all users in the group. Then I try:

```
SELECT *, max(post_date) FROM posts 
         WHERE user_id IN ($matches) 
         GROUP BY user_id 
         ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

But this doesn't work. How do I solve it?

Comment: Then another query to get the actual posts? There are more efficient ways of doing this, of course, but we'd need to see your schema.

Comment: Show what is $matches (structure).

Comment: Not sure I'm answering in the right place but $matches = implode(',', $userlist). An array of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the latest posts from group of users, you can do so by using a self join

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p 
JOIN(
SELECT user_id , max(post_date) post_date
FROM posts 
GROUP BY user_id  
) pp
USING(user_id,post_date)
WHERE pp.user_id IN ($matches) /* i assume here you have user ids like IN (1,2,3)*/
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
"SELECT *, max(post_date) FROM posts 
           WHERE user_id IN (".implode(',',$matches).") 
           GROUP BY user_id 
           ORDER BY post_date DESC "
```

Comment: he might also need to explicitly include user_id in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: It will work ONLY if he has simple array ($matches).

Comment: @mckurt he maybe included it in `select *`

Comment: This is the same as mine, right? ( I've already done implode). So I guess it should work, I'm on the right path. (Sorry, sometimes things like this is to much for my brain's two programmer cells)

Comment: you have done implode? why you didnt show it then and you showed the variable in IN clause and you didnt say anything about it if its array or string or what , i just guessed is an array

Comment: Sorry. I solved how to get selected users. My problem is not that but how to get latest post from that set of users.

Comment: then use LIMIT 1 in the end you get the latest post

Comment: I get the posts but the first ones. Maybe the problem is the post_date field, it's a date field not datetime. Could that be the problem?

Comment: edit your question and add the needed informations please , your data, table and wished result , so i can understand instead of be in chat with you here in comments.

Comment: Be aware that using IN has a 1000 item limit, so if your user group has 1001 users and you implode it into that SQL statement, the SQL will not execute.